# Why is getattr() so much slower than self.__dict__.get()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

The example below is from a REST database driver on Python 2.7.

In the `__setattr__` method below, if I use the commented out `getattr()` line, it reduces the object instantiation performance from 600 rps to 230.

Why is `getattr()` so much slower than `self.__dict__.get()` in this case?

```
class Element(object):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self._client = client
        self._data = {}
        self._initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        #_initialized = getattr(self, "_initialized", False)
        _initialized = self.__dict__.get("_initialized", False)
        if key in self.__dict__ or _initialized is False:
            # set the attribute normally
            object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
        else:
            # set the attribute as a data property
            self._data[key] = value
```

Comment: On a side note, if you are having such a performance difference, do cache `self.__dict__` in a local variable - even for only two access to it. (`dict_ = self.__dict__` at the start of `__setattr__`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short: because `getattr(foo,bar)` [does the same thing as `foo.bar`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr), which is not the same thing as just accessing the `__dict__` property (for a start, `getattr` has to select the right `__dict__`, but there's a whole lot more going on).

An example for illustration:

```
>>> class A:
...   a = 1
...
>>> class B(A):
...   b = 2
...
>>> dir(B)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'a', 'b']
>>> B.a
1
>>> B.__dict__
{'__module__': '__main__', 'b': 2, '__doc__': None}
>>> B.__dict__['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
>>> B.__dict__.get('a')
>>>
```

Details contained in, or linked to here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html (search for "getattr").

Comment: @bereal: you need to re-read things. The necessary operations for foo.__dict__.get() are a proper subset of getattr().

Comment: @bereal Bear in mind that python bytecodes do not correspond to primitive operations. You can have a very small amount of bytecode to call a very complex function, while one simple expression can generate a lot more bytecode. Also, what bukzor said is correct and relevant.

Comment: @bereal In no way does this disprove that `foo.__dict__` does the same as `getattr(foo, '__dict__')`, because it is possible for calling `getattr(foo,'__dict__')` to be more efficient than dereferencing an arbitrary attribute.